# Как вставить новый элемент в блок не в конец, а в определённое место?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, есть родительский элемент с вложенными в него дочерними элементами:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-stops="1"></div>
    <div class="child" data-stops="3"></div>
</div>
```

Я хочу, чтобы дочерние элементы были отсортированы согласно атрибуту `data-stops`. То есть, если мне попадается элемент с номером 0, то он должен быть вставлен в начало, а если попадётся номер 2, то он должен быть вставлен между 1 и 3. Я бы мог использовать методы `$.insertAfer()` или `$.insertBefore`, но я не могу заведомо знать, какой номер мне попадётся в цикле. Это может быть число от 0 до 6.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
let elem = document.createElement("div");
let number = 2;
elem.className = "child";
elem.innerText = number;
elem.setAttribute("data-stops", number);

for (let i=0; i<parent.children.length; i++){
if (parent.children[i].dataset.stops - 1 == number){
 parent.insertBefore(elem, parent.children[i])
 break;
}
if (i == parent.children.length - 1){
 parent.appendChild(elem);
}
}
```

```css
.child{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child" data-stops="1">1</div>
    <div class="child" data-stops="3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - использовать флексбокс c назначением детям CSS-свойства `order`, и вообще не беспокоиться о порядке следования элементов в разметке:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent'); 
for (let el of parent.children)
  el.style.order = el.dataset.stops; 
for (let el of getTestElements()) {
  el.style.order = el.dataset.stops; 
  parent.appendChild(el); 
}

// все что ниже - для проверки 

for (let child of parent.children)
  child.textContent = child.dataset.stops; 

function getTestElements() {
  return [7, 2, 9, 4, 6, 8, 3].map(n => {
    let el = document.createElement('div'); 
    el.classList.add('child'); 
    el.dataset.stops = n; 
    return el; 
  }); 
}
```

```css
.parent { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-stops="1"></div>
    <div class="child" data-stops="5"></div>
</div>
```

---

Или, можно искать позицию при вставке элемента (тот же смысл что и в предыдущем ответе, но значимый код тут немного проще для понимания):

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent'); 
for (let el of getTestElements()) {
  let child, i = 0, stops = el.dataset.stops; 
  do {
    child = parent.children[i]; 
  } while (i++ < parent.children.length && child.dataset.stops < stops); 
  parent.insertBefore(el, parent.children[i - 1]); 
}

// все что ниже - для проверки 

for (let child of parent.children)
  child.textContent = child.dataset.stops; 

function getTestElements() {
  return [7, 2, 9, 4, 6, 8, 3].map(n => {
    let el = document.createElement('div'); 
    el.classList.add('child'); 
    el.dataset.stops = n; 
    return el; 
  }); 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" data-stops="1"></div>
    <div class="child" data-stops="5"></div>
</div>
```

***P.S.:** объявление через `let` в теле цикла абсолютно нормально: например, при типовой конструкции вида `for (let something ...)` тоже создается новая переменная на каждой итерации - оптимизатор позаботится об этом.*

Comment: Уважаемые, хоть поясните причину минусовки данного ответа.

Comment: С флексами интересная реализация. На счет понимания кода - кому как). Минус не мой. мой плюс)

Comment: @Дмытрык, ваш ответ тоже непонятно за что минуснули (+), видимо это кто-то раздает просто по доброте душевной :]